# Whats wrong in the following code?

Tags: php

I have tried the following code but is show some error. Please tel me whats wrong with the following code?

```
 <?php

    public $PreviousId;
    public  $HasNextcandidate= $this->HasCandidateValue();

    public function HasCandidateValue()
    { 
    return ($PreviousId!=NULL);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You tell us what the error is first. Then we'll tell you what's wrong.

Comment: "is show some error" isn't a very specific error description.

Comment: ....and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot call a method (or any statement) in the `public $property` declaration. That's a compile-time directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign values to member variables using expressions including function/method calls.

So `public  $HasNextcandidate= $this->HasCandidateValue();` is not valid. You need to do something like:

```
public  $HasNextcandidate= '';
```

and then in your constructor do:

```
$this->HasNextcandidate = $this->HasCandidateValue();
```

Comment: Thank you @John.
But If I try following code it shows error: Could you please help me?

class CandidateModel extends Candidate
{
  public $HasCandidate=' ';
$this->$HasCandidate=$this->HasPreviousCandidate();
public function HasPreviousCandidate()
{ 
return ($PreviousId!=NULL);
}
}

Comment: Once again, without knowing the error message it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Actual error is :

 "syntax error, unexpected '$this', expecting 'function'"

Comment: @Rocky - you need to put code inside functions. The only parts of a class that aren't in functions are the lines where you declare and initialise your properties.